# ReactJS - props or propTypes?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I'm reading about props from open source, I see the use of `props` and `propTypes` to declare properties obtained from the parent. What is the difference between the two? Which one should be used?

For example:

**props** [source code](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/7d49ef4cc9a350f7eb247518551dd0f1dd3e11ae/app/containers/App.js#L6-L8)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  props: {
    children: Children
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**propTypes** [source code](https://github.com/web-pal/react-trello-board/blob/2c60bded2d051cd3d423ff4ed552451de0e8761a/src/containers/Board/Board.js#L25-L30)

```
export default class Board extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    getLists: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    moveCard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    moveList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    lists: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Props are the actual properties sent to a react class. The propTypes are used to define what properties the class is supposed to receive. So you should use both [More about props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)

Nice thing about proptypes is it helps ensure the correct type is sent for every property since you define what they should be... Meaning you will receive a console warning saying invalid prop type passed to component. [More about propTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: In the docs from props you've linked, it says that props are read-only. So, I guess I should not use that in the first example of my question. I could use `defaultProps` instead. Thanks for posting SO docs! Didn't know such thing existed.

Answer (score 2):

Difference is:

**props**:

Used to pass data/function from parent component to child component. It will be an `Object`, all the values that you send from parent component will become the part of this. Let say you are passing 3 values from parent `a='1' b={this.b.bind(this)} c={}`, then your props object will look like this:

```
{
   ...
   a: ...,
   b: ...,
   c: ...,
   ...
}
```

**proptypes**:

Used to specify the type of `props` that you passed from parent component, whether it will an `array, function, object, string, number etc`. Lets say these values are passed from parent then in child component you can define the proptypes like this:

```
static propTypes = {
    a: PropTypes.string,
    b: PropTypes.func,
    c: PropTypes.object,
}
```

**How it helps in the Development process**: When you define the type of props in child component, then each time its values will get checked and if it receives any value other than specified type, it will throw a warning.

One more important thing is, it help to others also when a team is working on same task. It basically tells that, these are the values that you are passing from parent component and these are the types of the values, so no need of checking the parent component for details about those `props`.

Comment: It seems like I should not define props in a child component since they are immutable

Comment: didn't get you, can you explain more ?

Comment: **props are immutable** means the values that you passed from parent component in child, that you can't change in child component, you can only use those values.

Comment: I understand. Just wanted to clarify that my first example was re-defining `props` in a child component which is not allowed. I will define from a parent component. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

**props** are the immutable data sent to a react component by a parent. Note that it could be functions as functions are first class citizens in Javascript.

**propTypes** are used to validate the type of the prop value. It helps in defining the types of the prop value(s).